# Java - Sorting An Array List By File Size

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am creating a class that will take in a number, say 10, and create an ArrayList of Files no greater than 10. Basically my program scans a directory and the sub-directories and gets all of the files. It keeps adding the biggest files in size to the array list, so at the end, I will have an ArrayList of files who are the biggest in file size.

However, I do not know how to get an element of the ArrayList who has the smallest file size out of all Files in that List. If the ArrayList is fully populated, I need to run a check: If the next file is bigger in size than the smallest file in the list, I need to delete that smaller file from the list and add in the bigger one. So how do I retrieve the smallest file in the ArrayList?

```
package pkgfinal;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 *
 * @author Sameer Anand
 * 
 */

public class TopN {

    ArrayList<File> fileNames;

    int numberOfObjects;

    public TopN(int numberOfObjects) {

        numberOfObjects = this.numberOfObjects;

        fileNames = new ArrayList<>(numberOfObjects);

    }

    public void add(File f) {

        // Add The File To The Array List

        // If The List is Not Fully Populated, Add The File To The List

        // Otherwise, Check The Length of The File Coming In.
        // If The Length of The File Coming In Is Greater Than The Size
        // Of The Smallest File In The List, Delete The Old File & Add
        // in The New File

        if (fileNames.size() < numberOfObjects) {

            fileNames.add(f);

        } else {

            // Do The Check

        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would not use an ArrayList for this. You need the collection of file names to be sorted at all times. A TreeSet, with a suitable Comparator, would be better.

Answer (score 0):

Use two variables to track the lowest value and its current location; each time you add a new file do a check to see if the new file is smaller than the current smallest file, if so save the size of the file and its location as the new smallest value.

Or as you create your list sort it from smallest to largest or largest to smallest so that you always know the location of the smallest file.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop through the ArrayList and see which one's smallest! (This will be faster if you keep the ArrayList sorted, but it probably won't make much difference when the number of objects is fairly small).

```
fileNames.get(i).length() //returns the filesize of the i'th file in the ArrayList
```